# How to recreate EntityManagerFactory between tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

I need to recreate the EntityManagerFactory between tests to ensure my sequences are reset in the JPA sequence generators to match the database.

I either need to recreate the EMF, or reconnect to the datasource based on the current settings.

Although spring-boot runs with an EMF named 'default', creating this again from

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
```

fails with

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default
```

even though that's the one created my Spring boot.

Is there a simple thing I am missing here?

Comment: Have you included the hibernate-entitymanager or hibernate-core dependency in your pom.xml file?

Comment: Hi, no - I am using spring-boots transient hibernate dependency.  I cannot find a hibernate-entitymanager on maven?

Comment: I think you should add it. Hibernate-enititymanager is deperecated, I think. The new "version" of it is hibernate core.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```